# Soft body object stuck in original position of 'collision' object. Basic physics simulation problem

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, collision, soft-body

so I have this book object and papers inside of it. I've turned on collision on the book cover, soft body on the papers inside of it and I have a force field to push the pages to the side while the book covers open apart. For some odd reason, the pages hit the original place of the book covers, as if they were not animated and stay there. Almost like an invisible wall is keeping them there. Here is the blender project: https://mab.to/AHfwEoFHC

Pic:[image]

I am new to blender and I just wanted to make this simple physics test work, so I can understand it better. Any overall tips will be greatly appreciated too! :)